# python 3.4 regular expression windows registry

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a regular expression to return the characters between the last \ and the closing ] from some .reg files

so far i can get it to work using with no spaces in the last key:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\foo\bar\keypath]

using `(?<=\\)(\w+)]`

but this can't handle any spaces in the last entry e.g:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\foo\bar\key path]

i've many different keys and some have are 2 words while some are not.
i'm still trying to get to grips regular expressions.

Comment: Hover the mouse over the [regex] tag for this question, then click on "info". Read the regex info there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this alternative:

```
(?<=\\)[^\\]+(?=]$)
```

---

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/hF6cQ2/2)

Explaining:

```
(?<=\\)        # starting with a '\' but without taking it 
[^\\]+         # ANY character EXCEPT '\' - as many as possible
(?=]$)         # till the ending ']' character - without taking it
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `\w` matches alphanumeric and underscore, but not space.

Change it to:

```
(?<=\\)([\w\s]+)]
```